# Washing machine drain hose too long?

Tags: pipe, washing-machine, hose

So, I just bought a new washer and dryer and the drain hose for the washer ended up being a little too short so I bought a hose extension and a clamp to extend the hose. The way I have it running now it creates a little U trap and water will remain inside after a load. Should I just cut this down and run it directly upwards into the pipe? Will that cause any backflow issues or would it be fine?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What does the manufacturers instructions say about length and height of drain hose?  Think that will be hard on the drain pump of the washer.

Comment: The manual was pretty basic about installing the drain hose.

• The drain must be installed in accordance with 
any applicable local codes and regulations.
• Make sure that the drain hose is not stretched, 
pinched, crushed, or kinked.
• Do not install the drain hose with the end lower 
than 29.5 inches (75 cm) or higher than 96 
inches (244 cm) above the bottom of the washer 
or more than 60 inches (152 cm) away from the 
washer.

Comment: Sounds like the machine was designed with the exit of the hose well above the machine in mind. So as long as you stay within those limits there will be no issues and without a scale in your images my best guess is that you are within them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your replies ratchet, I ended up just trimming down the hose because having that loop started to bother me. Also, I was afraid the hose being that long would wear out the pump and hose quicker.

I actually made some improvements to the hose as well because I was able to zip tie the drain hose clip that I previously wasn't using. So now the hose is even more secure.

Also, I checked the hoses after a couple of loads and there is no water in them so the machine does a good job at draining. The bottom of the washer to the top of the hose is 69" so it's within spec as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This will probably be easier on the machine's drain pump in the long run.  Unnecessary loops can cause air bubbles that restrict flow.   Good idea.  However regarding backflow, there will be backflow caused by the net vertical distance from the machine's drain outlet to the top of the pipe.    It doesn't matter how many  extra loops there are on the way.  There might be a backflow preventer in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment about the manufacturer instructions your installation is fine (as far as I can tell without a scale).

The excess hose drooping down is not an issue because they are designed to fit into a cubby where the only way to place the drain is to do the wiring and hoses with the machine outside the cubby and then push the machine into it with the slack of the hoses ending up drooping down behind it. Which will create the exact same U-trap situation you are seeing with no reasonable way to avoid that. So the bit of remaining trapped in the drain hose is of no issue